# iTunes does not play non-Apple Music songs which were synchronized with iCloud Music Library on Windows

Tags: itunes, icloud, windows, music

I'm facing the following scenario: I live in a country where a certain album from a band I like isn't available on most (if not all) streaming services. I own a physical copy of the album, and I have imported it to my computer and storage clouds.

When evaluating Apple Music, I noticed that on the Mac I'm able to upload songs to the cloud (iCloud Music Library). I thought "this is it, Apple Music is going to be great!".

However, on my Windows PC, while I'm able to download the songs, I'm not able to play them using iTunes specifically. Every other music player works just fine for the same file iTunes should have no issues reproducing. The songs show up on the library, together with all other musics and playlists I have access, but then when I click the play button over the song, iTunes just get stuck on 0:00. If I try to play another song, then it will play it just fine, as long as it is not a song downloaded from iCloud Music Library.

So why iCloud Music Library exists, if the player doesn't allow me to play it? Or is this a bug? I noticed that the first song of the album is playing just fine, but all the other songs are not.

I've checked the iTunes folder permissions for the current user, and I have full access to it.

## Update to the question information

I own a 13-inch early 2015 Macbook Pro, where the original files are. I also own a custom built Windows 10 PC (latest updates applied to both systems). I've tried the latest version of iTunes on the Windows PC. First I downloaded it from the Windows Store, but it didn't work (same error described on the question), so I uninstalled it and then installed using the .exe installer from Apple's website. Same error occurs.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what format the music you imported is in (mp3, mac, ogg, etc.) Please add that to your original question. Also O/S versions and iTunes version would be helpful.

Comment: Do you still have an Apple Music subscription? You need either Apple Music or iTunes Match to use the iCloud music library, and need to download everything before your subscription ends if you don't plan to renew or continue past the trial.

Comment: @SteveChambers I've added OS info.

Comment: @user3052786 Yes! I still have the Apple Music subscription. It is on the trial, and I can stream music within iTunes. I cannot play the songs from the iCloud Music Library though.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that you said you could download the files already. Can you check the files (right click then show in explorer on windows, I think) for integrity, content, etc. using a different media player/inspector?

Comment: @user3052786 I believe I mentioned I can play them with other media players, no? So the files are all ok! I used VLC and Media Player to play them. All of them.